# How to remove the language information in a bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, zotero

In Zotero, there is a 'language' field which is filled out with the appropriate languages of the bibliography item. However, it is shown as such in the bibliography. I think it would be better to omit. Is there another way to remove the language from the bibliography then to delete the field in Zotero?

[image]

```
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  maxnames=2,
  backend=biber,
  safeinputenc,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
```

and at the end of the document:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

Comment: Show us a minimal compilable document along with a sample `.bib` entry that shows *how* you are generating the bibliography.  Without that, there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: none of the standard bibligraphy styles would use that field, so you are using one that is, but you have not shown any relevant code.

Comment: This is not a compilable document, and you haven't shown us a sample `.bib` file entry either.

Comment: you tagged the question bibtex but now you have provided more of a fragment it's clear you are not using bibtex at all but biber,

Comment: Note: the content of the language field should contain the language of the bibliography item itself, not the language of the publication! It should be entered in the format 'en-US', 'fr-FR' etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can clear selected fields/lists/names using `\AtEveryBibitem{...}`.  Since `language` is a list, we use `\clearlist` to clear it.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Test2001,
    Author = {A Test},
    Language = {English},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {This is the title},
    Year = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  maxnames=2,
  backend=biber,
  safeinputenc,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Test2001}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1 Why is `clearlang=true` option not enough?

Comment: @CyriacAntony The `clearlang=true` option only clears the language field for entries that match the main language of the document as specified by `babel` or `polyglossia`.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But, in a beamer document I tried, the main language given as option to babel was english, but 'English' wast still showing in bibliography even though `clearlang=true` option was given.