# `\fulllcite` vs bibliography listing with Biblatex when fields are removed

Tags: biblatex, fullcite

The Biblatex documentation says "the `\fullcite` command prints a verbose citation similar to the full bibliography entry". There are some differences though, and some questions/answers here about that, like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135930/use-bibentry-with-biblatex) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/biblatex-fullcite-produces-different-result-from-bibliography-entry).

Here is another way they differ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% Don't want to see "language" field.
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This uses a [suggested method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401020/how-to-remove-the-language-information-in-a-bibliography) of removing the `language` field. It is removed from the bibliography, but not from the `\fullcite` output. How can I get rid of it there as well?

The output:

[image]

Comment: `\AtEveryCitekey` should work, but a source map may be an alternative for clearing the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\AtEveryBibitem` indeed does not affect `\fullcite` because it is a citation command, and not a bibitem. But you can use `\AtEveryCitekey` for this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% Don't want to see "language" field.
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{language}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

But, given what you want to do, perhaps using a source map changing the actual data `biber` takes into account would be a good idea:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% Don't want to see "language" field.
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=language, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In either case, the output is:

[image]